# Second ethernet port missing

Tags: networking

From a couple of weeks I have had two ethernet ports on my ubuntu 22.04; one was integrated and the other one was just added with a board on the PCI bus.

They was named `enp3s0` and `enp4s0`

Today the new one stopped working.

"stopped" means that is totally undetected.

This happened right after a reboot to force an update, so I guess it is due to a bug.

The system log says

```
Aug 13 12:14:38 lello kernel: [    0.562099] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168d/8111d, 00:e0:ff:68:4e:8f, XID 283, IRQ 32
Aug 13 12:14:38 lello kernel: [    0.562103] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
Aug 13 12:14:38 lello kernel: [    0.582409] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth1: RTL8168g/8111g, c0:3f:d5:96:0c:7b, XID 4c0, IRQ 41
Aug 13 12:14:38 lello kernel: [    0.582414] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth1: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
Aug 13 12:14:38 lello kernel: [    0.633458] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth1
Aug 13 12:14:38 lello kernel: [    0.656147] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
Aug 14 14:15:11 lello kernel: [    0.675283] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g, c0:3f:d5:96:0c:7b, XID 4c0, IRQ 40
Aug 14 14:15:11 lello kernel: [    0.675288] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
Aug 14 14:15:11 lello kernel: [    0.686380] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
Aug 15 09:43:36 lello kernel: [    0.667173] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g, c0:3f:d5:96:0c:7b, XID 4c0, IRQ 32
Aug 15 09:43:36 lello kernel: [    0.667177] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
Aug 15 09:43:36 lello kernel: [    0.682630] r8169 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
```

I think it is matter of the name: one is "RTL8168**g**" and  the other is "RTL8168**d**".

Anybody has the same issue, or can suggest me something?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you say "undetected" ? Update the question with the command and output why you say "undetected".

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got the reply, so far. "Undetected" means that the kernel does not detect it. Now I took  the same cable from the same wall plug and it works only in the main Ethernet on the main board. The trials led me to the conviction that this card (PCIe) has a slightly loose connection for my chassis: too late to send it back to BigAZ :( .

Comment: Without doing nothing this morning both was working: ```ifconfigg 
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.64  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e21a:d00a:102c:edc4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:e0:ff:68:4e:8f  [...]
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::8771:7580:53d2:f01a  ```

Comment: Doing nothing -> random contact = loosy
But both are Realtek.
I bet on the loosy.

Comment: Reminder, this is not a forum. Please add all relevant information to the question, not the comment.